# Unable to Vertical center, Text View "CCCC" in Android Studio

Tags: android

Returns error as "The attribute `android:layout_centerVertical` is not supported here.". Help me with any modification in the code

Program details is below:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Head_text_view"
        android:text="VIP List"
        android:background="#a4c639"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <TextView
        android:text="AAAAA"
        android:background="#a4c639"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <TextView
        android:text="BBBBB"
        android:background="#a4c639"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <TextView
        android:text="CCCCC"
        android:background="#a4c639"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="24sp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use layout_gravity="center_vertical" or gravity="center_vertical" which one suits for your need or you can use layout_centerInParent="true" depending on your needs, I would also recommend you use layout_toLeftOf, layout_toRightOf, layout_toBottomOf, layout_toTopOf="@+id/id" etc..

You can play with the width as well with combination of gravity e.g. layout_width="match_parent" and gravity="center"